Why does this power supply switching not work?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have a voltage source (a LiPo battery). It powers up a voltage divider made of two resistors of 220k and 1M. The 1M resistor can be shorted via a switch. The tap of the divider goes to the gate of an NMOS. The source of the NMOS is connected to the voltage source's negative potential and the source is connected to my system's ground (represented by RLOAD). I want to use the switch to power up my system from the battery or not. Why does this not work?
RD3P100SNFRA Datasheet

What is your system? Where does it connect? A proper schematic is needed.

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have represented my system using a resistor (RLOAD) and by "the battery" I meant the voltage source. I also edited the text within my question. I hope I made myself clear now

Is 100Ω a representative load? Is 37 mA your expected load current?

Yes, that is the expected load current (I only want to power the load when the switch is in the other position)

What does "not work" mean?

When measuring the voltage drop on RLOAD, it is 0 V regardless of the state of the switch (it should be 3.7 V in one of them)

Are these measurements from an actual, physical circuit or from the simulation? If they are actual measurements, then post a picture of the setup. If it is the simulation, move the ground symbol to the negative terminal of the battery.

The RD3P100SNFRA is rated to be "on" at 4V, but not 3. Are you sure your choice of voltage divider and transistor are appropriate here?

If you have a switch that controls a transistor that controls the load, why not just use the switch directly with the load? What is the purpose of this circuit with transistor if it can work without?

The choice of the voltage divider resistors might not be okay, I am open to suggestions. The purpose of this circuit is to allow the RLOAD circuit to be switched on or not. Its mean power consumption is around 30mA, but it also sometimes needs to be able to draw around 500mA, so the MOSFET is quite needed.

@Justme I need to use a MOSFET because the physical switch that I am using cannot support more than 100mA.

The simulation fails because of what MathsKeepsMeBusy said, so accept that answer, not this one. Make sure your simulated MOSFET has the same \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ as the real one, which is (worst-case) +2.5V. There are other things to consider though.
The potential divider formed by R1 and R2 is reducing \$V_{GS}\$ to \$\frac{1M}{1M+220k}=80\%\$ of the supply, which is about +3V. This is probably too close to \$V_{GS(TH)}=+2.5\$, for any significant load. It might be OK for \$\frac{3.7V}{100\Omega}=37mA\$ of drain current, but if your load requires more than that, you may be disappointed.
You can improve things by removing R2 altogether, which would cause \$V_{GS}=+3.7V\$, while the switch is open.
You should refer to fig. 5 (a graph of \$I_D\$ vs. \$V_{DS}\$), on page 5 of the datasheet, to see roughly how this transistor will perform, when it's required to switch more drain current \$I_D\$. Whatever \$V_{DS}\$ you find from that graph, given some \$I_D\$ and \$V_{GS}\$, is voltage that will be lost across the transistor:
$$ V_{LOAD}=3.7V-V_{DS} $$

CircuitLab does not have a model for the RD3P100SNFRA. You changed the name of another MOSFET model to RD3P100SNFRA, but the parameters for that model did not change. The threshold voltage for the model you are using is set to 4.0 V, so with a 3.7 V supply, the MOSFET will never turn on. Change the threshold voltage in your model to 2 V, and your circuit should work.

Update: it was a faulty MOSFET, the circuit works, thanks y'all!
